# How to obtain the surface from the cloud point, which contain only external, visible points ?(Matlab)

Tags: matlab, cloud, point, visible

I have a cloud of points in the 3d matrix. Each column of this matrix contains different coordinate (x,y,z) of the point. I need to find a way to obtain only external points which are visible from one direction of view and put them to another matrix. Or in other way I need to remove a points which are overshadowed. I haven't got the slightest idea how to do it. If anyone could help,I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Would [convhull](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/convhull.html) do what you need?

Comment: Firstly thank you Sam for your answer. Convull help me when I need to obtain external points of the entire cloud . However I need to get points only visible from the current viewing direction.